# docker container exits because of "std in is not a tty"

Tags: docker, xvfb, amazon-ecs

We are starting a container and run task using aws ecs service, the image got pulled successfully according to the task definition but when the container trying to run the task it exited because of "stdin is not tty". We manually reproduced that error by running `docker run {image_name}` but didn't figure out a way to fix it. Here's the output:

```
Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
Initializing built-in extension XTEST
Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
Initializing built-in extension SYNC
Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
Initializing built-in extension RENDER
Initializing built-in extension RANDR
Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
Initializing built-in extension RECORD
Initializing built-in extension DPMS
Initializing built-in extension Present
Initializing built-in extension DRI3
Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
Initializing built-in extension XVideo
Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
Initializing built-in extension SELinux
Initializing built-in extension GLX
stdin: is not a tty
```

We are using Xvfb to run tests and here are the related dependencies in our dockerfile

```
# install virtual display 
RUN apt-get -qy install xvfb
RUN apt-get -qy install x11-xkb-utils
RUN apt-get -qy install xserver-xorg-core
RUN apt-get -qy install xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable xfonts-cyrillic
```

Does anyone happen to know how to fix this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly: when you run the container, do you use `-t`?